# Iterate over list of dicts for calculation of population density

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python, so I apologise if this is straight forward. Other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152431/iterating-over-list-of-dictionaries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864007/python-3-5-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries)) have addressed lists of dicts, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

I have a list of dicts for each geographical area:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'},
                {'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'}]
```

I merely want to calculate the population density for each area, by dividing the `'population': 'value'`, by the `'area': 'value'`. This calculation should create a new item.

The results should look like this:

```
results = [{'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10', 'pop_density': 2},
           {'id': 'a', 'population': '30', 'area': '5', 'pop_density': 6}]
```

Comment: Can you do it for a single dictionary? Do you know about for loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Alter the dictionaries

You can simply iterate over every dictionary, and associate `'pop_density'` with the population density:

```
for v in list_of_dicts:
    v['pop_density'] = float(v['population'])/float(v['area'])
```

We need to use `float(..)` to convert a string `'20'` to the number `20`. We can use `int(..)` if all values are ints. But perhaps it is safer to work with floats.

## Copy the dictionaries

In case you want to create a *copy* of the `list_of_dicts`, you can use list comprehension:

```
[dict(v,pop_density=float(v['population'])/float(v['area'])) for v in list_of_dicts]
```

Generating:

```
>>> [dict(v,pop_density=float(v['population'])/float(v['area'])) for v in list_of_dicts]
[{'population': '20', 'area': '10', 'pop_density': 2.0, 'id': 'a'}, {'population': '20', 'area': '10', 'pop_density': 2.0, 'id': 'a'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Changing original dictionaries

You can simply iterate over your list of dictionaries and the calculations. Make sure to round the result since you want an integer:

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'},
                {'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'}]
>>> 
>>> for d in list_of_dicts:
    d['pop_density'] = int(d['population']) // int(d['area']) # round result by using //


>>> list_of_dicts
[{'pop_density': 2, 'population': '20', 'id': 'a', 'area': '10'}, {'pop_density': 2, 'population': '20', 'id': 'a', 'area': '10'}]
>>>
```

### Creating new dictionaries

**Python 3**

If you want a *new* list of dictionaries, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'},
                {'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'}]
>>> 
>>> [{'pop_densitiy': int(d['population']) // int(d['area']), **d} for d in list_of_dicts]
[{'area': '10', 'population': '20', 'id': 'a', 'pop_densitiy': 2}, {'area': '10', 'population': '20', 'id': 'a', 'pop_densitiy': 2}]
>>>
```

**Python 2**

Note the above uses the dictionary unpacking operator that is only available in python 3. If using Python 2, you'll need to use the `dict` constructor:

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'},
                {'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'}]
>>> [dict(d, pop_densitiy=int(d['population']) // int(d['area'])) for d in list_of_dicts]
[{'pop_densitiy': 2, 'population': '20', 'id': 'a', 'area': '10'}, {'pop_densitiy': 2, 'population': '20', 'id': 'a', 'area': '10'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the existing indices and add a new one to them:

```
results = []
for item in list_of_dicts:
    item = item.copy()  # since we want a new dict - mind you this is a shallow copy
    item["pop_density"] = int(item.get("population", 0)) / float(item.get("area", 1))
    results.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_dicts = [{'id': 'a', 'population': '20', 'area': '10'},
                {'id': 'a', 'population': '30', 'area': '5'}]
[dict(j) for j in [ list(i.items()) + [ ('pop_density', int(i['population'])/int(i['area'])) ] for i in list_of_dicts ] ]
```

Output:

```
[{'area': '10', 'id': 'a', 'pop_density': 2.0, 'population': '20'},
 {'area': '5', 'id': 'a', 'pop_density': 6.0, 'population': '30'}]
```