# How to loop multi-variable data in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How to loop multi-variable data like this in python ?
I have latitude and longitude data and I want to pass all these value and run it for 5 times.

e.g.

**round 1**
lat  = 13.29 , longitude = 100.34
city = 'ABC'

**round 2**
lat  = 94.09834 ,longitude = 103.34
city = 'XYZ'

,...
,..
,round 5

Very new to python world.
Thank you for every kind comment and suggestion :)

Comment: Does this data already exist in your program? What do you mean by "pass all these value and run it for 5 times"? You can make a program with a list containing 5 "lat/long/city" objects, then iterate over the objects and do something with the data. But without more details it's unclear what you'd like to achieve

Comment: If your five rounds are in a list of dictionaries then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864007/python-3-5-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
cities = ["Rome", "NYC"]
latitude = [41.2925, 40.730610]
longitude = [12.5736, 73.935242]
for (a, b, c) in zip(longitude, latitude, cities): #zips the lists together
     print ("long = %s, lat= %s, city:%s" % (a, b, c))
```

> Output :

```
long = 12.5736, lat= 41.2925, city:Rome
long = 73.935242, lat= 40.73061, city:NYC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data in a proper data structure which will allow you to loop it, I would suggest storing it as a list of dictionaries.
It would look something like this

```
data = [{'city':'city1','lat':'lat1','alt':'alt1'},
{'city':'city2','lat':'lat2','alt':'alt2'}]
```

The iteration over the data would look as following:

```
for d in data:
    print(f" lat: {d['lat']}, alt: {d['alt']} , city: {d['city']}")
```